# Envoking Scheduled Task or Service in .net

Tags: .net

So I come across many resources taking about why Scheduler is better then Windows service etc. But confusion remains for my requirement, 
 - I have a UI app where end users can run a job immediately or "schedule" it for later with information of start time and owner saved in a SQL table.
Since end user(s) [max 100] can give in any time - this is not periodic or with set intervals - whats best to use in this case ?
Also are there any predefined templates to carry out the above task ?

EDIT for More information: 
JOB = calling a stored procedure. I.e. if user clicks to run now, the SP is executed. Else s/he can put it to execute in future with date time information saved in a table. 
UI = ASP.net application.

Comment: The information provided is not enough to give an useful suggestion. Try to explain your setup/project with info like where this is scheduled-DB/WindowsService. How its already done? What is that you expect? What framework you use for UI - Mobile/Winform/WPF? etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *Windows Service* with a Timer object to temporarily check (every *x* seconds, for example) the scheduled jobs and execute them if the correct time.